# Illumination from a narrow luminous panel

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am struggling about this problem, I have this geometry setup

[image]

According to the book

$$
dh = D \sec^2\theta \ d\theta
$$

So, the illumination reaching point $p$ from this narrow surface is

$$ 
dE_p = \frac{Lw}{\pi r^2}\cos\theta \sin\theta \ dh
$$

I can't figure out how $dh$ is calculated

You can read the book here: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.284487/page/n271/mode/2up

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: $h/D=\tan\theta$, so differentiate with respect to $\theta.$

Comment: @KevinPWalker thanks, solution was so easy, it was always in front my eyes!